# Visual studio using html images not displaying

Tags: html, visual-studio

hello hope you all doing good
so im trying add picture  in visual studio using html but this show for me
like its show here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Niug.png)

but like when I add it this how it display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYGK5.png)
how I can solve  this please like did I miss anything important ??

btw I put this path `C:\Users\MAJID\Desktop\sakura\sakurashop\sakurashop\templates\cover.jpg`

like this `<img src="C:\Users\MAJID\Desktop\sakura\sakurashop\sakurashop\templates\cover.jpg"><br/><br/>`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Sff.png)

I dragged the pictures and add them in template folder

Comment: Your `src` path is probably wrong.

Comment: how I can know the right one ?? like i copy the path and its like C:\Users\MAJID\Desktop\sakura\sakurashop\sakurashop\templates\cover.jpg but still not worked

Comment: Hard to explain how to "get the right one" in a comment. Could you edit your question to include your folder structure?

Comment: @Spectric okay i will

Comment: @Spectric i add more details thank you

Comment: don't add absolute paths in the `src` attribute

Comment: Switch the source with `cover.jpg` and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src = "image_name.jpg"/>
```

Try replacing the image_name with
a real image name (e.g "benzo.jpg")

make sure the image you want to use  is at the same file  as the html code you have created

Comment: PLEASE TRY USING LOWERCASE, it's less shouty and easier to read.  You can use `**bold**` text for emphasis if needed.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/MAJID/Desktop/sakura/sakurashop/sakurashop/templates/cover.jpg">
```